# Illusionist's bracers and werewolf rulings

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Lets assume that I equip an [Illusionist's Bracers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366426) on [Mayor Of Avabruck](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mayor%20Of%20Avabruck).

When he flips on the trigger of not casting a spell, can he technically flip twice, meaning that he would turn into a werewolf and then back again, or does he remain as a werewolf permanently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Illusionist's Bracers](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=366426) only copy *activated* abilities.

> 112.3b Activated abilities have a cost and an effect. They are written as “[Cost]: [Effect.] [Activation instructions (if any).]”

Most transform cards, like werewolves and Delver of Secrets, have *triggered* abilities. Illusionist's Bracers have no effect on them. They will, however, double the activated abilities of [Bloodline Keeper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Bloodline%20Keeper), causing it to flip twice when it transforms.

All of the abilities of [Mayor of Avabruck](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Mayor%20of%20Avabruck) and [Howlpack Alpha](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Howlpack%20Alpha) abilities are triggered, so he won't benefit from Illusionist's Bracers unless you give him an activated ability from an outside source.

Comment: Note that the loyalty abilities of planeswalkers are activated abilities even though their artistic representation belies their true "[cost]: [effect]" form. Certain keyword abilities (e.g. Equip) are represent activated abilities.

Comment: Also note that planeswalkers are not _creatures_ and as such, can't be equipped (unless they turn into creatures, but when they turn back, the equipment falls off as a state-based effect)

Answer (score 1):

Mayor of Avabruck doesn't have any activated abilities, so I fear this is a bit of a nonbo.  Equipping him with Illusionist's Bracers won't usually do much...

Something like Civilized Scholar may reap you greater rewards.  If you activate HIS ability you will indeed get to use it twice (and transform to Homicidal Scholar and back again straight away.)

Comment: Ah I assumed so much of the cards forgot the ultimate rule of mtg. The "RTFC".